# React boostrap table`s responsive not working

Tags: reactjs

I added a react-boostrap table component to my web site as following.But it is not responsive.

```
import {Table,Container, Button ,Jumbotron} from 'react-bootstrap'
<div >
    <Table responsive striped bordered hover variant="dark" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
        </Table>
```

It`s original look is as following.
[image: When opoen in wide screen]

But when i decrease the screen size it look like as following(headers not showing and other details are stacked).
[image]

[image]

Can somebody show me the issue with my code

Comment: This is how it looks like when i inspect the element.it seems responsive class has applied.But its not working in the website

Answer (score 0):

Try linking their css file from their CDN in your html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table.min.css">
```

Comment: Also make sure the normal bootstrap is also linked in the html file.<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">